# Pyspark code for partitioned by department, sum by salary but it should show sum on first row only

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can anyone please help me with this?

I have an input table with `employee_name`, department, and salary. I want to add one column which is the sum of salaries department wise. But `sum_salary` should be printed on a single row only within that department partition.

Input table:

[image]

Output table :

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: please add the tables within the question as an inline table (not as an image). please add description of the issue and the requirements within the question. see [ask], [mcve] to know more.

Comment: Hi @samkart Thanks for the suggestion, but here i am not able to add those table as image. could you please find the link for input and output table as i have mentioned. thanks.